# Getting CORS error while working with OpenLayers v7.5.2

Tags: javascript, cors, openlayers, cross-origin-resource-policy, esmodules

```
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: 
The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at file:///C:/Users/kalam/Documents/my-ol-app/main.js. 
(Reason: CORS request not http).

Module source URI is not allowed in this document: 
"file:///C:/Users/kalam/Documents/my-ol-app/main.js".
```

Getting this error while working with `OpenLayers  v7.5.2`

Unable to know how to solve this error

Comment: some browsers don't like using `file://` instead of `http[s]://` - simple solution is to use a web server of some sort